# Installing Cypress release edx fullstack in Windows7 using Virtual Box and Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, edx, openedx

I am following 8.5 Install Open edX Fullstack in "Installing, Configuring, and Running the Open edX Platform" Release (October 2, 2015).

- mkdir fullstack
- cd fullstack
- curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edx/.......(omitted)
- vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostsupdater
- vagrant up

During the "vagrant up" step, it "created" the virtual box OK since it "appeared" on my Oracle VM Vitural Box manager. However, the "vagrant up" step kept on running while printing the following messages. Eventually, it destroyed the VM and quit.

`==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
 ==> default: Booting VM...
 ==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.0
==> default: Checking for host entries
==> default: adding to (C:/Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts) : 192.168.33.10  preview.localhost  # VAGRANT: 8f87a49f1
aae27b0a96e16269847ad4 (default) / d270d099-e1a7-44d0-b95c-8e2581568495
==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
C:/Users/user/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-hostsupdater-0.0.11/lib/vagrant-hostsupdater/HostsUpdater.rb:82:in`initiali
e': Permission denied - C:/Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts (Errno::EACCES)
        from C:/Users/user/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-hostsupdater-0.0.11/lib/vagrant-hostsupdater/HostsUpdater.rb:82
in `open'
        from C:/Users/user/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-hostsupdater-0.0.11/lib/vagrant-hostsupdater/HostsUpdater.rb:82
in`addToHosts'

and more of these lines followed....

I am using Windows 7 and most recent versions of Virtual Box and Vagrant.
I would really appreciate if you let me know anything I may try to solve this error.

(a debtor)<><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed the vagrant-hostsupdater that tries to add entry to `C:/Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts` but to do that you must be have elevated right. run your command prompt as admin (or UAC) and run `vagrant up` from there.

Comment: It worked, passed the vagrant-hostsupdater even though other problems popped up later. Thanx! (a debtor)<><